# Appium not clicking on button and Test is passed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

```
I am new in appium. So, i did complete setup and my application launch successfully. But after launching app, No click action is performed on element.

Code--->



package functionlity;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class Login {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void Loadsetup() {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "dcd9e0817d63");

        capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "6.0");

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.engagebeyond.load");

        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.engagebeyond.load.Splesh");

        try {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void Logincase_01() throws InterruptedException{


        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement w=driver.findElement(By.id("com.engagebeyond.load:id/c1"));
        System.out.println(w);
        w.click();



    }

}

Appium Log--->



> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app D:\Appiumnewproject\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk --no-reset --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
> info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
> info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"D:\\Appiumnewproject\\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk","address":"127.0.0.1","noReset":true,"logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
> info: Console LogLevel: debug
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Android","VERSION":"6.0","deviceName":"dcd9e0817d63","appActivity":"com.engagebeyond.load.Splesh","browserName":"","appPackage":"com.engagebeyond.load"}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.7.0_79)
> info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : VERSION
> info: [debug] Using local app from command line: D:\Appiumnewproject\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session 2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9
> info: Starting android appium
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
> info: Java version is: 1.6.0_16
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: [debug] Using adb from D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? false
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
> info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
> info: Found device dcd9e0817d63
> info: [debug] Setting device id to dcd9e0817d63
> info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 wait-for-device
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "echo 'ready'"
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: Device API level is: 23
> info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
> info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: 
> info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools_1.6.jar" "stringsFromApk" "D:\Appiumnewproject\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk" "c:\Temp\com.engagebeyond.load" 
> info: [debug] No strings.xml for language '', getting default strings.xml
> info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools_1.6.jar" "stringsFromApk" "D:\Appiumnewproject\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk" "c:\Temp\com.engagebeyond.load"
> warn: Error getting strings.xml from apk
> info: [debug] Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Could not decode arsc file
>   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:54)
>   at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:540)
>   at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:76)
>   at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:68)
>   at io.appium.apktools.StringsXML.run(StringsXML.java:84)
>   at io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:31)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Expected: 0x001c0001, got: 0x00000000
>   at brut.util.ExtDataInput.skipCheckInt(ExtDataInput.java:48)
>   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.StringBlock.read(StringBlock.java:43)
>   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:100)
>   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:81)
>   at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:49)
>   ... 5 more
> 
> warn: Could not get strings, continuing anyway
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "echo '{}' > /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
> info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
> info: [debug] Using aapt from D:\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\26.0.0-preview\aapt.exe
> info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\26.0.0-preview\aapt.exe dump xmltree D:\Appiumnewproject\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk AndroidManifest.xml
> info: [debug] Set app process to: com.engagebeyond.load
> info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
> info: [debug] Checking app cert for D:\Appiumnewproject\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" D:\Appiumnewproject\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk
> info: [debug] App already signed.
> info: [debug] Zip-aligning D:\Appiumnewproject\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk
> info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
> info: [debug] Using zipalign from D:\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\26.0.0-preview\zipalign.exe
> info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\26.0.0-preview\zipalign.exe -f 4 D:\Appiumnewproject\Load-com.engagebeyond.load-33-v3.3.apk c:\Temp\117320-672-a5var0\appium.tmp
> info: [debug] MD5 for app is 1ef6766ab258f337503deaecd232d00c
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/1ef6766ab258f337503deaecd232d00c.apk"
> info: [debug] Getting install status for com.engagebeyond.load
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "pm list packages -3 com.engagebeyond.load"
> info: [debug] App is installed
> info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
> info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 push "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
> info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
> info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
> info: Starting App
> info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
> info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
> info: [debug] No matching processes found
> info: [debug] Running bootstrap
> info: [debug] spawning: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.engagebeyond.load -e disableAndroidWatchers false
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] json loading complete.
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
> info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "dumpsys window"
> info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"\/data\/local\/tmp"}
> info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":false}
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.engagebeyond.load/com.engagebeyond.load.Splesh"
> info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.engagebeyond.load" and activity "com.engagebeyond.load.Splesh" to be focused
> info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "dumpsys window windows"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
> info: [debug] Device is at release version 6.0.1
> info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
> info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
> info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 16397.110 ms - 74 
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9 {}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"Android","VERSION":"6.0","deviceName":"dcd9e0817d63","appActivity":"com.engagebeyond.load.Splesh","browserName":"","appPackage":"com.engagebeyond.load"},"platformName":"Android","VERSION":"6.0","deviceName":"dcd9e0817d63","appActivity":"com.engagebeyond.load.Splesh","appPackage":"com.engagebeyond.load"},"sessionId":"2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9"}
> info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9 200 7.609 ms - 641 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"Android","VERSION":"6.0","deviceName":"dcd9e0817d63","appActivity":"com.engagebeyond.load.Splesh","browserName":"","appPackage":"com.engagebeyond.load"},"platformName":"Android","VERSION":"6.0","deviceName":"dcd9e0817d63","appActivity":"com.engagebeyond.load.Splesh","appPackage":"com.engagebeyond.load"},"sessionId":"2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9/timeouts {"type":"implicit","ms":15000}
> info: [debug] Set Android implicit wait to 15000ms
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9/timeouts 200 6.394 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9/element {"using":"id","value":"com.engagebeyond.load:id/c1"}
> info: [debug] Waiting up to 15000ms for condition
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.engagebeyond.load:id/c1","context":"","multiple":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.engagebeyond.load:id/c1","context":"","multiple":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.engagebeyond.load:id/c1 using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.engagebeyond.load:id/c1]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"}}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9/element 200 32.339 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9/element/1/click {"id":"1"}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"1"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"1"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9/element/1/click 200 64.664 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9"}
> info: [debug] Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down...
> info: Shutting down appium session
> info: [debug] Pressing the HOME button
> info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s dcd9e0817d63 shell "input keyevent 3"
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
> info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
> info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 68.444
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
> info: [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
> info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
> info: [debug] We shut down because no new commands came in
```

please suggest me solution. here what is wrong with my code.I am new in appium. So, i did complete setup and my application launch successfully. But after launching app, No click action is performed on element

Answer (score 0):

If you see your log file, it has this output -

```
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"1"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2980c636-5d38-4e5c-8c75-0717d1da26b9"}
```

This means that Appium was able to successfully click on the element, based on the identifier you provided. Maybe there is an issue with the identifier you have used, and that's why appium is not clicking on the correct element.

Would it be possible for you to share the UIAutomatorViewer screenshot, so that we can have a look at the object properties?

Comment: i cant able to add screenshot.

Comment: but i am putting resourse Id as a locator.

Comment: I am also try other application but still its not possible to perform click option